# Movilizer- Upload Json to master data pool through Eclipse Connector

Tags: movilizer, honeywell

I need to call a web service which will return me a list of users in json format. I need to upload this json to master data pool in movilizer cloud. Is there any way i can do it(as i can see in confluence it is written that from eclipse it is not possible). Is there any other alternative to do it?

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

do you have an example how the json looks like?

Basically this is how the request should look alike:

```
<masterdataPoolUpdate pool="CUSTOMIZING_UI">
<update key="47" group="DEFAULT">
  <data>
    <json><![CDATA[[
      {
        "name":"icon",
        "valb64":""
      }
      ]]]></json>
  </data>
</update>
```

If its flat see above otherwise you would need to do:

```
<masterdataPoolUpdate pool="123myPool" >
<update key="myKey" group="myGroup">
    <data>
        <json>
            <![CDATA[
                [
                    {
                        "name"   : "entry_0",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "name"   : "entry_00",
                                "valstr" : "value_00"
                            },
                            {
                                "name"   : "entry_01",
                                "valstr" : "value_01"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            ]]>
        </json>
    </data>
</update>
```